# Facebook Graph API returning only id and name

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to use Facebook's graph API and trying to get details like email, profile picture etc. But graph api returns only id and name none of the other attributes. In facebook app console I'm able to see whatever I'm trying is approved by default, please find screenshot below:
[image]

But if I try with this URL: `https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name,email&access_token=<my token>`

I get only below data:

`{"id":"148487658972025","name":"Saraag In"}`

If I try in graph explorer, I get this message

> The field 'email' is only accessible on the User object after the user grants the 'email' permission.

But when login page comes, I have given all permission, still it is not giving above fields. Can anyone kindly help me? I am new to Facebook's graph api.

Comment: The users email also need to be validate and they need to have one